# Animating multiple uiviews

Tags: ios, uiviewanimation

I have to views pannelView and contentView. Pressing a button hides pannelView and expands contentView to the full screen. I have been using this code:

```
    if (sender.selected==NO) {
            pannelView.hidden=YES;
            contentView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 90, 768, 434);
            sender.selected=YES;
        }
        else {
            pannelView.hidden=NO;
            contentView.frame=CGRectMake(186, 90, 580, 434);
            sender.selected=NO;
        }
```

It switches b/w two states without animation. What should I do to animate them to look pretty? Moreover when some other button is pressed, contentView is updated. I want this view to hide and show with animation in the time content is loading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [UIView documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW108) and the section on block based animation.

A simple example:

```
CGRect newFrame;
BOOL hidePanelView;
if (sender.selected==NO) {
    hidePanelView = YES;
    newFrame = CGRectMake(0, 90, 768, 434);
    sender.selected=YES;
} else {
    hidePanelView = NO;
    newframe = CGRectMake(186, 90, 580, 434);
    sender.selected=NO;
}

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
    contentView.frame = newFrame;
    pannelView.hidden = hidePanelView;
}
```